# Battery temp too low?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and it doesn't want to charge. When I plug it it it says "Charging Paused: Battery temperature too low." Sometimes it will charge but most times it won't. It's really annoying and I can't afford to buy a new battery or phone. Any suggestions? Please, I'm desperate.

Comment: Have you tried basic troubleshooting (rebooting phone, clearing system cache, even full factory reset)?

Comment: Well, at least you know it isn't on fire. :-)  (Or the temperature sensor has already burned up...)

Comment: I have already done a factory reset, I left it off all night, I let it die completely and then tried to charge it but it won't charge more than 1%.

Comment: What's the warranty status? Is it already void? What do you see if you plug your phone, while it's shut down?

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen anything like this before.

I decided to look it up to see whether it has been resolved before. According to forums the reason for this issue is that the battery has been tampered with. Now I'm sure you haven't touched your battery so I kept looking. The main other suggestion I could find was that the battery is simply damaged, and a lot of people within forums are suggesting that a new battery may be required. I see that you say you can't afford to buy a new battery, so may I request that you search online to see, and if there are any other methods available, to try them? If you do have a small source of income from anywhere batteries are not too expensive online, so maybe have a look if you can :)

I wish you luck,

Regards